# Volley Android - GET para retornar lista de vídeos de uma playlist - JAVA

Tags: java, android, get, volley, youtube-api

Olá, estou usando a bibliteca android [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley?hl=pt-br) para fazer uma chamada GET (https) para retornar pra mim o JSon dos vídeos de uma playlist específica qualquer.
Basicamente a minha requisição GET atual é essa:

```
String url ="https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PLl-K7zZEsYLlRjj-mSComCq3Vd4IJese1&key="+YoutubeConfig.getApiKey();
```

Onde `YoutubeConfig.getApiKey();` é a minha chave de API criada no console de desenvolvedor com chave AUTH 2.0 e cadastrado no SHA-1 do aplicativo.

Ao tentar fazer o GET na solução, o código me retorna um ErrorResponse e "null" como código de mensagem, assim:

```
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PLl-K7zZEsYLlRjj-mSComCq3Vd4IJese1&key="+YoutubeConfig.getApiKey();

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        Log.i("onResponse", "onResponse: "+response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("ErrorOnResponse", "onErrorResponse: "+error.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

logCat:

```
2020-11-17 10:04:22.256 23662-23662/com.appX.a2f20 I/ErrorOnResponse: onErrorResponse: null
```

Ou seja, a solicitação GET nem validada conseguiu ser, não estou entendendo porque, o formato me parece estar correto e a playlistID é válida, alguém sabe o porquê deste erro acontecer?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver, o código de response que estava retornando era 403-Forbidden

Traduzindo basicamente àquela minha chave de API não tinha acesso a API Youtube de solicitações HTTP. O que eu fiz?

Fui no meu console das APIs do Google e adicionei no meu "Bibliotecas" a biblioteca de API do Youtube Data API V3, adicionando-a no meu projeto já existente, após isso, pude ir na minha chave de API usada no App e inserir na restrição a biblioteca Youtube Data API v3 que agora estava elegível para ser selecionada (como não tinha sido adicionada nas bibliotecas ela não era exibida antes, então achei que não era necessária).

Agora a solicitação GET funciona bem e me retorna o Json corretamente.
Acho que o maior problema não está na biblioteca Volley, mas sim na falta de clareza do Google na documentação ao falar sobre as bibliotecas que devem ser adicionadas no projeto para que sejam exibidas nas restrições de API.